# SSRS report error :XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://report_name

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i'm getting `XML parse error` in `SSRS reports` it was working fine before

> SSRS report error :XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: `http://report_name`

why so any guess where i need to do change or look over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve: Run SSRS Manager and bind this folder to specific host and/or
IP address.